# NULL value returned when using SUM function on two columns while populating table in SQL Server 2008 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

`INSERT INTO table` is producing a `NULL` value for the returned recordset. I'm trying to add the `SUM(m.earnings + m.fpearn) from pfinancial` table and userid & minpay from the userbase table.

What am I doing wrong? Also is there a better way to reiterate through the temp table of id's ?

From the tables below I should populate the `publsher_monthly` table with one unique id per userid, the `minpay` amount from the `userbase` and the sum of the `m.earnings + m.fpearn` columns from the `pfinancial` table

`publisher_monthly` table

```
pmuseris   pmminpay   pmearnings
5          20         75
6          30         27
```

`userbase` table

```
userid  minpay
5       20
6       30
```

`pfinancial` table

```
userid  earnings   fpearn
5       10         30
5       20         15
6       15         12
```

My query:

```
DECLARE @realuserid bigint

CREATE TABLE #tmppmuserids(
   idx bigint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1),
   tmppmuserid bigint NULL
)

INSERT INTO #tmppmuserids
  SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM pfinancial

DECLARE @i bigint
DECLARE @numrows bigint

SET @i = 1
SET @numrows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmppmuserids)

IF @numrows > 0

WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM #tmppmuserids))
BEGIN
   SET @realuserid = (SELECT tmppmuserid FROM #tmppmuserids WHERE idx = @i)

  --PROBLEM HERE
  INSERT INTO publisher_monthly (pmearnings, pmuserid, pmminpay)

    SELECT  
        SUM(m.earnings + m.fpearn), MAX(@realuserid), MAX(u.minpay) 
    FROM pfinancial m 
    INNER JOIN userbase u on u.userid = m.userid 
    WHERE 
       m.userid = @realuserid AND 
       (m.created >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()),0)) AND
       (m.created < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
  --END PROBLEM

  SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #tmppmuserids
SELECT * FROM publisher_monthly

DROP TABLE #tmppmuserids
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place an `IsNull` around them:

```
SELECT SUM(IsNull(m.earnings, 0) + IsNull(m.fpearn, 0))
```

or even around the whole thing:

```
SELECT IsNull(SUM(m.earnings + m.fpearn), 0)
```

Comment: How does placing an ISNULL around the returned values going to help? The problem is the NULL values being returned. The columns from which I'm grabbing from aren't NULL, but somehow the recordset returned is null. There's something wrong with my query. I need to fix the query

Comment: you should post some sample data then to provide a clearer picture of the problem

Comment: Just added sample data. forgot to do that. sorry.

Comment: I just used your sample data and query and I am not getting a null result. The data is loading into the publisher_monthly table correctly. Of course, I don't have your created field in my data so the issue might be there.

Comment: You're going to laugh at this. I used -1 in the month function to return the data from the last month. While testing, I only had the current month in the date column. Hence I was getting NULL values. I just saw that. Thanks for the time and the help.

Comment: better you use the latter. If m.earnings and f.pearn are NOT NULL, and you put ISNULL inside of SUM, your query will be dog slow. I'd once seen a very slow query because of non-judicious use of ISNULL, putting them inside on just about every aggregate function. And besides, ISNULL on outside works even there's no rows that met the criteria. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64881/1

Comment: @Patriotec happy to help you debug. :)

Comment: +1 For suggesting the ISNULL around the whole expression, and a nudge to 10k rep, welcome to the club! ツ

Comment: @MichaelBuen thanks I have been trying to get there. soooo close!